# Access android custom ActionBar from Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I created a class that extends ActionBarActivity and displays a custom XML. That class is extended by almost all my activities.

I want to access an element of that custom XML from one of my activities. Let's say I want to change the background of item2 when I'm in Activity2.

In my activity's onCreate method, after setContentView, I tried:

```
View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_menu, null);
ImageButton rewards_link = (ImageButton) cView.findViewById(R.id.rewards_link);
rewards_link.setVisibility(View.GONE); // For test purpose
```

Even if the button id seems correct, the changes doesn't apply. Any ideas ?

Comment: How does that just inflated `cView` relate to what you add to the action bar?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to understand your question. I'm just trying to access my custom ActionBar then hide one of its item.

Comment: Why are you inflating a new layout that has nothing to do with your action bar?

Comment: Sorry I may not have explained well. The Layout I'm inflating is the customView I'm setting in my ActionBar (`getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_menu);`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the custom view via `getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_menu);` (or `getSupportActionBar()` for v21 of AppCompat), then you can access those views by using `findViewById()` directly as the view is part of your view hierarchy just like views added via `setContentView()`:

```
ImageButton rewards_link = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rewards_link);
rewards_link.setVisibility(View.GONE); // For test purpose
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do so, `rewards_link.setVisibility(View.GONE);` returns NullPointerException.

Answer (score -1):

Use #getCustomView

```
View view =getSupportActionBar().getCustomView(); ImageButton imageButton =
 (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_back); imageButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v){ 
   // Your code here ...
  } 
});
```